# jQuery Slideshow in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I currently have a small slideshow on my webpage that is being powered by jQuery.

When I test my webpage in Firefox the slideshow is lined up exactly where I want it. However, in Safari and Chrome the slide show is offset by about 15px.

The images are retrieved in my HTML through a normal unordered list. As shown below:

```
<div class="slideshow">
     <ul>
         <li><img src="Images/slideshow/1.png" alt="LXA 1" /></li>
         <li><img src="Images/slideshow/2.png" alt="LXA 2" /></li>
         <li><img src="Images/slideshow/3.png" alt="LXA 3" /></li>
         <li><img src="Images/slideshow/4.png" alt="LXA 4" /></li>
         <li><img src="Images/slideshow/5.png" alt="LXA 5" /></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS for the slideshow class is:

```
.slideshow-div{
    width:1040px;
    padding-left:325px;
    padding-top:0px;
    height:287px;   
    background-image: url('../Images/slideshow-background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And of course when I downloaded the jQuery plugin I got a seperate CSS file to go with it. But I won't include it here.

I am aware that things act differently in different browsers. But this is my first time I have had to work with it. So I am unsure how to protect against that.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted indicates anything. Most likely the issue is with some other, surrounding, elements or CSS.

Comment: I understand that. I just don't understand why it works in firefox but nothing else.

Comment: I was confused by your title. This has nothing to do with jQuery. Without a link or a jsfiddle. Anything said here will be just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked with "Firebug" what causes the offset? I know some browsers give `ul`s `margin-left` while others give them `padding-left` - perhaps you forgot to reset both?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a css class which positions the elements perfectly on a specific browser which is currently giving you trouble. Next, determine which browser is being used and call the css class which corresponds to that browser.

There are many ways to cater for cross-browser functionality - this is just one method. It all boils down to requirements and preference :)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful insight on cross browser functionality. Which was main focus of my question.

Answer (score 0):

If all images in your slideshow DIV 'slides' that means jquery function is working correctly.
So the real problem is not with your jQuery script but in CSS file. You provided information about CSS only for slideshow-div element. You shouldn't leave UL and LI without styling.

Is it very good practise to reset your CSS before creating your site. You can follow the instrucions here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Reseting your CSS will change your currently view, so correcting will be needed.